# git fetch fetch between two commit hashes

Tags: git

For performance I have cloned via `git clone <git_url> --branch=<branch> --single-brach --depth=1`

But when I do git log it only shows 1 entry (because depth=1).

How can I make git retrieve only the commits in the current branch?

I've tried `git fetch origin <start_sha>...<end_sha>` but that results in `Invalid refspec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first the options [`git fetch --depth=x` or `git fetch --deepen=y`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---depthltdepthgt).

That will increase the number of commits fetched.

You can either directly enter the number of commits needed (if you know how many commits you have between `<start_sha>...<end_sha>`.
Or increase incrementally, until the fetch you want includes `<start_sha>`.

Comment: in my case, I do know the number of commits! thanks